# Keeping mysql.user host up to date when restarting instances on Amazon EC2

Tags: domain-name-system, mysql, amazon-ec2

Whenever I restart an Amazon EC2 instance, it generates a new IP address and a new Private DNS. This is problematic since I then have to go into the database and update mysql.users to add the new Private DNS as a host.

Can I use an Elastic IP or something like that to prevent myself from updating the MySQL database every time an instance restarts or will it always assign a new Private DNS?

Comment: Just put in `%` and give up on authenticating based on the source IP?If you are paranoid about security setup a VPN of some sort to tunnel the mysql traffic over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a VPC. Amazon's VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) runs your instances in an isolated network and is very useful for stuff like static internal IPs for instances. It doesn't cost anything extra and is easy to configure.

Answer (score 1):

You could permit the 10.% range and use the amazon firewall to limit by security group which would be the simplest option.

If you want to explicitly maintain a list of internal IP's and issue grants for them you could boot strap your instances to call a script or dump the list of available instances.  You could use python and the boto library for this with something like,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from boto import ec2
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YOUR_KEY'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'

filters = {'instance-state-name' : 'running'}
ec2conn = ec2.connection.EC2Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
reservations = ec2conn.get_all_instances(filters=filters)
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
for i in instances:
  print i.private_ip_address
```

You can issue other filters too such as for only specific groups or check for specific tags.